# Universal instantiation $x \mapsto A(xyx)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm wondering if I can make the following transformation by universal instantiation of $x$ for $A(xyx)$?

$$\forall x \exists z F[A(xyx)z] \mapsto \exists z F[A(A(xyx)yA(xyx))z]$$

it feels kinda weird to transform something simple like $x$ into something with multiple parts like $A(xyx)$.... otherwise, I don't see any violation of rules.

Comment: In the LH expression, $x$ is a bound variable. In the RH expression $x$ is free variable. This means you've used $x$ to mean two different things in the same context. This is just plain bad practice. Since the first $x$ is bound, it can be replaced with any other letter with no change in meaning. Do you feel better about it when it is written like this? $$\forall u \exists z F[A(uyu)z] \mapsto \exists z F[A(A(xyx)yA(xyx))z]$$

Comment: No I do no feel any worse or better with this.  The rule doesn't say we must preserve boundness, it says we must preserve freedom.  I realize that what you've written is equivalent to what I have, and your $u$ (like my $x$ on the LHS) is just a dummy.  My question is two: (1) Can I make substitutions of $x$ which are complex, like $x \mapsto A(x)$, or what about $x\mapsto xy$, or what about $x\mapsto yz$, or $x\mapsto A(xyx)$ or $x \mapsto A(yz)$, provided that freedom is preserved and (2) Is my actual substitution fine?

Comment: Question (1) above is motivated because almost always the substitution is very simple like $x\mapsto s$, but it might be useful to do more complicated substitutions, in general..... but because all my substitutions, so far, have been like $x\mapsto s$ it feels weird to do anything more complicated.

Comment: You should feel FAR better about it, because your statement as given is nonsensical because you use $x$ to mean different things in the same context. It isn't about "preserving boundedness" versus "preserving freedom". It is about being clear. My version solves this nonsense you've created. As for your question (1). "for all" means exactly that. It does not mean "for only things that can be expressed in certains ways, and nothing else". If $f(x) = x^2$ then $f(y) = y^2$ but also $f(yz+7) = (yz + 7)^2$. Complexity of the substitution has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Actually, it has everything to do with "preserving freedom", it's given as a requirement in our textbook.  And saying that what I wrote is "nonsense" is comical because it turns out my answer is correct, as I got hold of a solution manual.